# EntityFramework Join table with more than 2 entities

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-5

I have 4 tables/entities which fall into two groups, alerts and recipients.  Either entity from a group can map to either entity of the other group (an Alert can have many Recipients and RecipientGroups and so on).

Tables:

- Alerts
- AlertGroups (1 to many relationship with alerts)
- Recipients
- RecipientGroups (many to many relationship with recipients)

Instead of making 4 jointables (AlertRecipients, AlertRecipientGroups, etc.) I want to make one join table with 4 columns, each column being a nullable FK for one of my entity types.

I've made the table in SQL, and set up my context using Fluent API like so:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<AlertGroup>()
                .HasMany(ag => ag.RecipientGroups)
                .WithMany(rg => rg.AlertGroups)
                .Map(m => m.ToTable("AlertRecipients")
                    .MapLeftKey("AlertGroupID")
                    .MapRightKey("RecipientGroupID"));

            modelBuilder.Entity<AlertGroup>()
                .HasMany(ag => ag.Recipients)
                .WithMany(rg => rg.AlertGroups)
                .Map(m => m.ToTable("AlertRecipients")
                    .MapLeftKey("AlertGroupID")
                    .MapRightKey("RecipientID"));
```

But I get this error:

> Schema specified is not valid. Errors:
>
> (251,6) : error 0019: The EntitySet 'AlertGroupRecipient' with schema
>   'dbo' and table 'AlertRecipients' was already defined. Each EntitySet
>   must refer to a unique schema and table.

Is there a workaround to do what I'm trying to do?

Comment: Just a wild guess.. I think an `AlertGroup` contains `Alerts`, etc.? Can't you restrict the associations to just one many-to-many association `AlertGroups`-`RecipientGroups`, where a group with 1 member acts as the single form? (Maybe with some special business logic). A junction table with nullable FKs is not a nice construct and a junction table with only a few allowed combinations of columns is not normalized and error prone. In the end maybe the best alternative is the 4 junction tables.

Comment: @GertArnold I understand it is not normalized, but 4 junction tables just seems unwieldy. Also I've got another set of relationships with a mapping of either of two entities to any or 3 entites (6 junction tables now) and I'd like to shove those all into one table as well.

Comment: I understand your objections. These junction tables drive me nuts too sometimes. Still, I'd prefer a succinct database model, 1 table for 1 association. A data model is so fundamental and hard to change later. Any compromise there with haunt you for years (I know, I've got some).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EF is not able to do that this way. With EF you need separate join table for every many-to-many relationship (because that is the way how you should do that). If you want to do that your way you cannot use many-to-many association in the mapping. You must instead "upgrade" your `AlertRecipients` to the real entity (another class in your model) and handle everything like one-to-many association.